# hidden attribute not working in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Code block originally...

```
<div class="content row">
  <img width="33%"  class="img-thumbnail img-rounded" src="foo">
  <img width="33%"  class=" img-thumbnail img-rounded" src="bar" >
  <img width="33%"  class=" img-thumbnail img-rounded" src="baz" >
</div>
```

Some Page DOM events after user requests change the HTML code block to...

```
<div class="content row">
  <img width="33%" class="img-thumbnail img-rounded center-block" src="foo">
  <img width="33%" class=" img-thumbnail img-rounded" src="bar"  hidden="">
  <img width="33%" class=" img-thumbnail img-rounded" src="baz" hidden="">
</div>
```

When the 
The page renders 
the hidden images are still displayed ? The images marked to be hidden don't get displayed, as expected, if `img-` classes are removed. But, I want the `img-` bootstrap classes.

How do I hide the images that are supposed to be hidden ?

PS- I am using Bootstrap 3.1.0

Comment: just use a hidden class. it is in bootstrap

Comment: OFFTOPIC:: admins should let people accept answers before 10 mins! it's really annoying to wait to select the the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be

```
<div class="content row">
  <img width="33%" class="img-thumbnail img-rounded center-block" src="foo">
  <img width="33%" class=" img-thumbnail img-rounded hidden" src="bar">
  <img width="33%" class=" img-thumbnail img-rounded hidden" src="baz">
</div>
```

You may also refer to the [Helper Class of Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes) to know about more similar classes

Comment: Dont forget to select it as answer if it helps, Just below the vote sign, You will find a tick sign such as in this [Image](http://pasteboard.co/ZNmuQBX.png), It will be green once you click on it.

Comment: sure will do. SO won't let me select an answer until 10 mins! It's really annoying! It's like SO is forcing me to waste 10 mins waiting around to tick the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-show-hide

> Showing and hiding content
>
> Force an element to be shown or hidden (including for screen readers)
>   with the use of .show and .hidden classes. These classes use
>   !important to avoid specificity conflicts, just like the quick floats.
>   They are only available for block level toggling. They can also be
>   used as mixins.
>
> .hide is available, but it does not always affect screen readers and
>   is deprecated as of v3.0.1. Use .hidden or .sr-only instead.
>
> Furthermore, .invisible can be used to toggle only the visibility of
>   an element, meaning its display is not modified and the element can
>   still affect the flow of the document.

"hidden" is a class name. You can apply it as a class.

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) tells you to use the following.

> Force an element to be shown or hidden (including for screen readers) with the use of .show and .hidden classes. These classes use !important to avoid specificity conflicts, just like the quick floats. They are only available for block level toggling. They can also be used as mixins.
>
> .hide is available, but it does not always affect screen readers and is deprecated as of v3.0.1. Use .hidden or .sr-only instead.
>
> Furthermore, .invisible can be used to toggle only the visibility of an element, meaning its display is not modified and the element can still affect the flow of the document.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using bootstrap you can use hide class like this way.

```
<div class="content row">
  <img width="33%" class="img-thumbnail img-rounded center-block" src="foo">
  <img width="33%" class=" img-thumbnail img-rounded hide" src="bar">
  <img width="33%" class=" img-thumbnail img-rounded hide" src="baz">
</div>
```

You can also use hidden class for different devices like hidden-sm, hidden-lg etc.

Comment: There is no hide class in bootstrap 3, Refer to my answer